# Http streaming using red5

Tags: red5, http-streaming

I wanted to perform http streaming from red5 server so as to use it to broadcast for Iphone. Can u guys suggest a way to do it. Is there a way to play rtmp stream from red5 in Iphone. Any help is appreciable

Comment: Welcome to SO :). Have you already tried something? Can you show us what you found out so far? If you haven't found anything so far, but have search, where and what did you search?

Comment: Thanks for responding quickly. There is something in https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/red5interest/pmDPldg1iC4 but I couldn't find a way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was involved in the discussion you linked. But I don't think that the project team has yet committed the HTTP Streaming components. There is also no documentation about it.

So if there is a possibility to do that you probably will need somebody from red5 developers to hire.

Sebastian

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I would like to know, is there any possibility to change the format of the video streamed from red5 using xuggler so as to use it for http streaming

Comment: Yes there are "any", people have shown demo applications doing that. But ... Xuggler project is no more active maintained, the founders are working for another company now, there has been less activity around the project for several years. And I think they do no more rely on Red5, since FFMPEG can stream RTMP natively. And of course Xuggler is a framework you first need to get comfortable with.